# i can't access service via k8s master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, microservices, cni

I'm learning k8s & nodePort

1. made 1 master node & 1 worker node at AWS EC2
2. installed k8s, kubeadm
3. Use flannel CNI
4. deployed a nodejs app. with port 3000
5. Attach a nodePort to nodejs app. so, 3000:31000
6. I expected that i access to that nodejs app outside ec2 with url : "[master-node-pub-ip]:31000"
7. But i can't access to "[master-node-pub-ip]:31000" and can access with "[worker-node-pub-ip]:31000"

I don't know what did i wrong...

How can i access that nodejs app via master nodes ip??

Thank you.

Comment: This is expected behavior. The master nodes manage the cluster, they are not the ingress point for service trafic.

Comment: you should expose your service by using ingress controller from the edge node. it is not a good practice by using ip to access your service. If you just want to access it from outside the kubernetes, you can use kube-proxy and access the pod with service ip.@mecha kucha

Comment: thanks!! i understood!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to install an ingress controller

I prefer the helm way:

```sh
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
```

Then you can access to you nodepert via the node public IP.

Comment: can you give an example for me?? i tried your comment, but it not works. EXTERNERL-IP of nginx-ingress is pending and can't access to my service with ingress